# Make Nginx send all errors to one page and POST the error ID?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, nginx

I was wondering if it is possible, to redirect all the Error Codes (404, 500, Etc.) to a single error document such as /error.php, and POST the Error code. For example, a 301 error would take the user to `example.com/error?err=301`.

I'd like to do this so I can make a PHP array of simplified error messages then just use the POST value to generate them without making a new errorpage every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way i think is to define all possible errors as single entry

```
error_page 400 /error.php?error=400;
error_page 401 /error.php?error=401;
error_page 402 /error.php?error=402;
...
```

but this is hard work and the number of redirects is limited... so you need to filter what error codes you need.

Comment: Forgot to flag this as the answer, thanks for your contribution.